# An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I get this error while "Connect via network" option in new version of XCode9 and iOS11.

[image]

I checked the "Connect via network" box. After few seconds XCode gives me this error:

"An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device"

Anyone facing the same issue?

### Configuration

- XCode Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)
- iOS 11 Beta 5
- iPad Air

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that error causes when device lost connection for a moment. it's happen when you have damaged (or very old) cable. How ironic... trying to connect a device for ones for been wireless anymore, but cable...

Answer (score 2):

I got same error in my case Quit Xcode after that restart clean and build its working fine .

Answer (score 0):

There might be more than one reason for this error:

> "An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this
>   device. (The service is invalid.)"

I hit this problem today after I transferred my iPad XCode project from one Mac to another.  I was pretty sure there was nothing wrong with my USB cable, it was working just fine on the other Mac with the same iPad.

So I did the old XCode standby voodoo solution:

1. in XCode, do a `Product->Clean Build Folder`;
2. quit XCode;
3. from the macOS Finder, delete the `DerivedData` folder for the project;
4. launch XCode, rebuild and run.

It works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was unplug the charger from the phone and replugged it back in. This solved it for me.