# iPhone can't be detected in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to install app on the iPhone(iOS 11.2.6) and iPad using Xcode 9.2.
It seems Xcode can't connect to the iPhone.

After build success， it stuck on tips as below

[error tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFEtS.jpg)

when goes to  window -> devices and simulators

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjMAl.jpg)

Help/Suggestion.

Many THX!!!

Comment: Here's a thread to watch on Apple's Dev Forum: [Could not write to the device in Xcode 9.2](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98305).  Not sure if it fully relates.

Comment: It seems not fully relates.

Answer (score 8):

Xcode and the GDB connection is quite temperamental. The device and your Mac can become unsynchronised with each other. My checklist for this sort of thing:

1. Restart Xcode.
2. Delete the .app from your iOS device, do a Clean then Rebuild.
3. Disconnect, reconnect device.
4. Restart iOS device (90% of the time it fixes things)
5. If all else fails, restart your Mac (unlikely but it did fix an issue once for me).

From question: [Error : The service is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Data remove process: https://www.macworld.com/article/2364290/ios/four-ways-to-delete-ios-apps.html

- Or please check your iphone and xcode update version of OS!

Do you sign in with your dev account with xcode? Example image given below:
[image]

You can try also with network connection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLwMY.jpg

Comment: I saw this question you mentioned. And I tried all the solutions that you listed. It sitll don't work.

Comment: Have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8 @zhan bobo

Comment: yes, I sign in my dev account and register my devices.

Comment: Yes, I already signed in and it looks just like your example image.

Comment: Same wifi connected in iphone and mac?? @zhan bobo

Comment: yes, the iPhone and Mac connect to the same wifi. window -> devices and simulators , the devices name do appear on left side without plug in my iPhone.

Comment: Ｉalready tried. However， it stuck on the same error connect via network.

Comment: It's may be your xcode problem :( try to restart and try again! Or reinstall it or try with another iphone to build your app.

Comment: It's really weird. I try to use Xcode 9.3-beta and other devices. The same error still exists.

Comment: On XCode 11, on the 'Signing & Capabilities' page, there is sometimes a 'Repair' button that appears along with the name of the device. Click 'Repair' and the problem is solved.

Comment: @AppreciateIt yup!

Comment: @RizwanShah Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figure it out how to solve it.
I have two iPhones, one is running iOS 11.2.2. It can be detected in Xcode 9.2. Another one running iOS 11.2.6 can't be detected in Xcode 9.2. I tried all the solutions above, it still not work.
After I upgrade the iPhone running iOS 11.2.2 to iOS 11.2.6. When I connect this iPhone to Mac, Xcode take a little while on "preparing debugger support on iPhone". Then anything just works fine. All devices can be connected in Xcode 9.2.
It seems some conflicts occur between two different devices running different iOS minor versions respectively.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who give me suggestions.
Many THX!!!

Comment: Congrats! But may be I told you in my comment section about that! Happy coding.

Comment: The same problem occurs again when I update my device to latest iOS  beta version. I install my apps by using TestFlight via iTunes Connect. (But you should join apple developer program first before using iTunes Connect services)

Comment: Yes you must have developer account!

Comment: this is what it ended up being for me.  I updated my XCode 3 months previous but apparently the most up to date iOS version didn't like it and it was too old.    C'est la vie! Updated and restarted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

- Delete derived data
- Disconnect the iPhone or Device which you are trying to installation of app.
- Restart the Xcode.
- Connect the Device
- Clean + Build
- Run the app.

Make sure you are using latest version of Xcode which is supporting the iOS 11.2.6.

Comment: Only the first step I haven't try yet. What do you mean by deleting derived data? And how to do that?

Comment: This may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587463/an-error-was-encountered-while-attempting-to-communicate-with-this-device

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9 and above you can run app without connecting it to mac.

1. First set the device lock in iPhone.
2. Then connect it to xCode and go to Window -> Device and Simulators.
3. Select your device from left side list and check Connect via Network checkbox.
4. Then disconnect the device and Go to settings and Enable Network sharing from Sharing setting.
5. Connect your iPhone to wifi of your mac and run the app.

It will work in Xcode 9 and above.

Comment: I tried connect it via network. However, it stuck on the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently installed/updated Xcode, make sure you install command line tool.